# Rails Active Storage + AWS Rekognition detect_labels: filtered labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-rekognition

I'm trying to get AWS Rekognition to work with Rails 6 rc3 with photos stored in S3 via Active Storage.

```
Aws.config.update({
      region: 'us-west-2',
      credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key], Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key])
    })

    rekognition = Aws::Rekognition::Client.new(region: Aws.config[:region], credentials: Aws.config[:credentials])
    @uri = @user.avatar.service_url
    @dir = @uri.split("/").fourth
    @key = @dir.split("?").first

    response = rekognition.detect_labels(
      {image:
        {s3_object:
          {bucket: 'bucket',
            name: @key,
          },
        },
        max_labels: 5,
        min_confidence: 70
      }
    )
    puts response
    @user.update(notes: response)
```

However the labels in the response shows 'FILTERED'

```
{:labels=>[{:name=>"[FILTERED]", :confidence=>99.28252410888672, :instances=>[], :parents=>[{:name=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

Doing the same thing over aws-cli shows the labels. Why does it show 'filtered' and how can I show the labels?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the `response` object and print the labels field if you want to see them them unfiltered:

```
response.labels.each { |label| puts(label.name) }
```